# CSS div position gets messed up on zooming the browser

Tags: css

I'm developing a website for Facebook application which is based on grid image layout. The following code works fine for me but when i zoom my browser everything gets messed up. browser with 100% zoom view works. please help me to find some other code if possible or fix the following code.

```
<style>
div.img {
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #0000ff;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }   

    div.img img {
        display: inline;
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }

    div.img a:hover img {
        border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    }

    div.desc {
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: normal;
      width: 120px;
      margin: 5px;
    }
 </style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="PHOTO" width="110" height="90"></a>
 <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="PHOTO" width="110" height="90"></a>
 <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="klematis3_big.htm"><img src="image3.jpg" alt="PHOTO" width="110" height="90"></a>
 <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm"><img src="image4.jpg" alt="PHOTO" width="110" height="90"></a>
 <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks good even after zooming http://jsfiddle.net/j7o2kqun/

Comment: there r four images in one row but when you zoom the line breaks and it becomes 2 images each row.

Comment: what do you want then keep them for and make them smaller?

Comment: if you want them to say in the same manner you need some javascript

Comment: so u want a code for that?

Comment: yes mustafa. please help me.

Comment: what's the correct behavior you want? For which browser do you need it? Maybe the flex-box propertys helps you to avoid javascript: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the fiddle of Sdghasemi. Added fallback for older browsers without width calculation function and set the image width to 100% and cleaned up the Html a little (closing image tags etc)
The reason that images where flowing out of the container div was the width and height attributes in the HTML. I set it now to 100% of the container. Meaning 100% -2px because of the border. Same with the image caption.

```
<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/110/90/" alt="PHOTO"/>
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/110/90/" alt="PHOTO"/>
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="klematis3_big.htm">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/110/90/" alt="PHOTO"/>
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/110/90/" alt="PHOTO"/>
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    height: auto;
    width: 24%;
    width: calc(25% - 22px);
    float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100%;
}   

div.img a:hover img {
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
}

div.img img{
    width: 99%;
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

div.desc {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/or2ua75e/5/

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to use CSS's `calc()` function to calculate the right width of every image on page resize or zoom:

```
width: calc(24.9% - 22px);
```

the reason i used 22px: `2 * (margin + border.width + padding)` for every image.

and use 24.9% instead of 25 for sure.

See working [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/sdghasemi/or2ua75e/)

Comment: thank you very much it helped me. but now one more problem i encountered with is that image caption runs out of the box. any solution?

Comment: any fiddle or illustration?

Comment: @Satish Gupta if the answer solved your problem, please accept it as answer!

Comment: sorry Sdghasemi, I'm new to stackoverflow. however this site has helped me much in my programming experience.